# DropDownListFor not setting the value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `dropdownlistfor` that is not working correctly. The values are not setting in that, but my database is returning.

```html
<div class="form-group  col-md-12">
    @Html.Label("Em alguma das ações cadastradas acima beneficiou os filhos dos colaboradores da empresa?")<span> *</span>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.PEAC_Respondente[x].PEAC_Acao_Social[0].FLG_RealizaAcoesParaFilhos, lstTpEmpresaSN, "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control col-md-6"})
</div>
<div class="form-group  col-md-12">
    @Html.Label("Em alguma das ações cadastradas acima houve participação de voluntários da empresa? *")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(c => c.PEAC_Respondente[x].PEAC_Acao_Social[0].FLG_AcoesVoluntariado, lstTpEmpresaSN, "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control col-md-6"})
</div>
```

Its inside the loop, when I select the values and save, it saves in database correctly, when I enter the page, the model is loaded correctly, but it doesn't set the value. The list I'm using is this.

```cs
    @{ var lstTpEmpresaSN = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Sim", Value = "1" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Não", Value = "2" }
        };
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work using a Select.

```
                                 <div class="form-group  col-md-12">
                                    @Html.Label("Em alguma das ações cadastradas acima beneficiou os filhos dos colaboradores da empresa?")<span> *</span>

                                    @{
                                        var idVoluntario = "PEAC_Respondente_" + x + "__PEAC_Acao_Social_0__FLG_RealizaAcoesParaFilhos";
                                        var nameVoluntario = "PEAC_Respondente[" + x + "].PEAC_Acao_Social[0].FLG_RealizaAcoesParaFilhos";
                                    }
                                    <select id="@idVoluntario" name="@nameVoluntario" class="form-control">
                                        @foreach (var item in lstTpEmpresaSN)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@item.Value" @(Model.PEAC_Respondente[x].PEAC_Acao_Social[0].FLG_RealizaAcoesParaFilhos.ToString() == item.Value ? "selected" : "")>@item.Text</option>
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```